# Copy and paste column data based on date specified

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

In an Excel worksheet, cell `C1` contains a date. I would like a macro that checks the date in `C1` and if the same date is mentioned in row 3, then copy all matching date data beneath it from `D6` downwards, paste to Sheet2, cell `B3` and also copy column `A` downwards from row `6` to Sheet2, cell `A3`.

Comment: .. What is the question?

Comment: How To Make A Macro Which Performs The Above, Thankyou

Comment: I have never worked with macros before, and have been racking my brain to get this to work, its been over a week now, please help urgently!!

Comment: Well, what have been trying for that week? Do you have any relevant code that you have issues with? =)

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel's macro recorder to record your keystrokes and mouse actions (as Excel actions) then inspect the resulting macro. Using Excel's help, check the topic *Create a macro* or visit http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-macro-HP005204711.aspx. This will get you started.

Comment: I have gotten way pass that, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you checking the date in C1 against any column in row 3? or in D3? or C3? It is not clear.
copy A6 down and D6 down, but switch column D to B on sheet2 and A to C on sheet2?

This could be easy if it were clearer what you are checking.